# Express - Multiple async requests from different endpoints

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, async.js

I'm developing an app with `NodeJS` and `Express`. The objective of this app is to provide data that is fetched from multiple different API endpoints, all in one single page.

Unfortunately, I'm relatively new with `NodeJS` and `Express` but already have done some research and I know that you can make multiple asyncronous requests with the
`async` module. However, I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem and need your help to get me back on the track.

I need to provide two asynchronous requests to get all the expected data and eventually link them together as one JSON. The requets are as follows:

**Request 1 - Tonight's Games**

First, I need to get the scheduled games for tonight `(http://exampleapi.com/api/v1/schedule)`
Outputted `JSON` data from this API endpoint is as follows:

```
{
  "date": "2016-12-15",
  "totalGames": 3,
  "games": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "link": "/api/v1/game/1"
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "link": "/api/v1/game/2"
     },
     {
       "id": 3,
       "link": "/api/v1/game/3"
     }
  ]
}
```

Underneath, there is a route from my file that does output the fetched `JSON` in a way explained above.

**Side note/problem:** While the `for` loop iterates over 3 times, a first object will be outputted three times instead of three different objects.

**server.js**

```
router.get('/test/schedule_test', function(req, res) {

    res.contentType('application/json'); // content type of the response object
    var url = 'http://exampleapi.com/api/v1/schedule'; // url of the api endpoint

    // make an request to the endpoint
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {

        // If the request was successfully made
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            var body = JSON.parse(body);
            var schedule, totalGames, date, games = [], id, link, game;

            // Schedule object
            schedule = {
                "totalGames": totalGames,
                "date": date,
                "games": games
            };
            schedule.totalGames = body.totalGames;
            schedule.date = body.dates[0].date;
            game = {"id": id, "link": link};

            for(var i = 0; i < schedule.totalGames; i++) {
                // Here's the part where I think I've made some mistakes and why it outputs a single object over so many times the value of "totalGames" is.
                game.id = body.dates[0].games[i].gamePk;
                game.link = body.dates[0].games[i].link;

                games.push({
                    "game": game
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json(schedule);

        } else {
            res.status(404).json({"error": true});
        }
    });
});
```

Next, I need to make an asynchronous request for each of the links provided by the link property value to fetch the the team-related data of each participating teams.

**Request 2 - Team-related data**

Expected `JSON` output from this API endpoint is as follows:

```
{
  "gameData": {
    "teams": {
      "away": {
        "link": "/api/v1/teams/1",
        "name": "Example team 1",
        "abbreviation": "EXT1"
       },

       "home": {
         "link": "/api/v1/teams/2",
         "name": "Example team 2",
         "abbreviation": "EXT2"    
        }
    },
    "venue": {
      "name": "Georgestown Palace, Manitoba"
    }
  }
}
```

Underneath, there is a route from my file that does output the fetched `JSON` in a way explained above.

**server.js**

```
router.get('/test/team_test', function(req, res) {

    // Note that these urls should be generated dynamically from the previous request
    var urls = [
        'http://exampleapi.com/api/v1/teams/1',
        'http://exampleapi.com/api/v1/teams/2'
    ];

    async.map(urls, function(url, callback) {
        // iterator function
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {

            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                // do any further processing of the data here
                var body = JSON.parse(body);
                var teams;

                // Away team
                var away_link, away_name, away_abbr;
                var away = {"link": away_link, "name": away_name, "abbreviation": away_abbr};

                var away_link = body.gameData.teams.away.link;
                away.link = away_link;

                var away_name = body.gameData.teams.away.name;
                away.name = away_name;

                var abbreviation = body.gameData.teams.away.abbreviation;
                away.abbrreviation = abbreviation;

                // Home team
                var home_link, home_name, home_abbr;
                var home = {"link": home_link, "name": home_name, "abbreviation": home_abbr};

                var home_link = body.gameData.teams.home.link;
                home.link = home_link;

                var home_name = body.gameData.teams.home.name;
                home.name = home_name;

                var home_abbreviation = body.gameData.teams.home.abbreviation;
                home.abbreviation = home_abbreviation;

                var arena = body.gameData.venue.name;

                teams = {
                    "teams": {
                        "away": away,
                        "home": home
                    },
                    "played_at": arena

                };

                callback(null, teams);

            } else {
                callback(error || response.statusCode);
            }
        });
    }, function(err, results) {

        // completion function
        if (!err) {
            res.contentType('application/json');
            res.status(200).json(results);
        } else {
            // handle error here
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

**Expected Result**

Lastly, I need to join these two different outputs into one `JSON` output. The expected result would look something like this:

```
{
  "date": "2016-12-15",
  "totalGames": 3,
  "games": [
     {
       // #1 joined object

       // data from the first api request
       "id": 1,
       "link": "/api/v1/game/1",

       // data from the second api request
       "teams": {
          "away": {
            "link": "/api/v1/teams/1",
            "name": "Example team 1",
            "abbreviation": "EXT1"
          },
          "home": {
            "link": "/api/v1/teams/2",
            "name": "Example team 2",
            "abbreviation": "EXT2"    
           }
        },
        "venue": {
          "name": "Georgestown Palace, Manitoba"
        }
     },


     {
       // #2 joined object
       "id": 2,
       "link": "/api/v1/game/3",
       "teams": {
          "away": {
            "link": "/api/v1/teams/3",
            "name": "Example team 3",
            "abbreviation": "EXT3"
          },
          "home": {
            "link": "/api/v1/teams/4",
            "name": "Example team 4",
            "abbreviation": "EXT4"    
           }
        },
        "venue": {
          "name": "Portsmouth Valley, New Jersey"
        }
     },

     {
       // #3 joined object
       "id": 3,
       "link": "/api/v1/game/3",
       "teams": {
          "away": {
            "link": "/api/v1/teams/5",
            "name": "Example team 5",
            "abbreviation": "EXT5"
          },
          "home": {
            "link": "/api/v1/teams/6",
            "name": "Example team 6",
            "abbreviation": "EXT6"    
           }
        },
        "venue": {
          "name": "Colorado Springs, Colorado"
        }

     }

  ]

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

For coordinating multiple asynchronous operations, I'd strongly recommend that you use promises.  If you make each one of your async operations return a promise, then you can use `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done and to have access to the data that each async operation fetched.

For example, if you had an array of endpoint that you wanted to fetch data from, you could do that like this:

```
const request = require('request');

// promisify the request module
function requestAsync(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, response, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                reject(new Error("response.statusCode = " + response.statusCode));
            } else {
                resolve(body);
            }
        });
    });
}


function getData(endpoints) {
    return Promise.all(endpoints.map(function(url) {
        return requestAsync(url);
    }));
}

let endpoints = [...];    // multiple endpoints to retrieve data from
getData(endpoints).then(function(results) {
    // results array contains all the results you can process here in the
    // order they appears in the array.
    // You can now organize the returned data into the final format you want here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error occurred here
});
```

Comment: What about the fact that some of the endpoint URLs are generated dynamically based on the link property value of previous request?

Comment: @B_CooperA - Obivously you have to do something more specific to your situation.  I'd have to understand exactly what you are trying to do because I don't see that situation illustrated in the code in your question.  I'd still use promises to coordinate async results, but there's isn't a generic answer for your specific situation.  I gave an answer for what I though you were doing which was fetching data from multiple independent endpoints in parallel and using the results to generate a page.